# Use EAP-TTLS certificate with Windows Phone

Tags: lumia, wifi, nokia-lumia-720

I'm trying to connect our university's WiFi network but it requires a TTLS (PAP) certificate for authentication. And there is no certificate for Windows Phone, only for Android, Windows, Mac OS and Linux. Is it possible to use one of these certificates with my Windows Phone

Comment: It looks like WP 8.1 supports this, are you running 8.1 yet?

Comment: @NeilTurner yes I'm using 8.1

Comment: have you tried installing the Windows one?

Comment: How can i install it @Thomas ? Our university providing an .exe file to install SecureW2 with certificate - http://www.saunet.sakarya.edu.tr/saunet/destek/?page_id=117 -

Comment: an .exe won't do you any good on a Windows Phone. You need the standalone certificate which you can install on your phone by sending it as an email attachment.

Comment: @Thomas but our university doesn't provide any standalone certificate file for Windows. They just providing a SecureW2 installation file and this file installing certificate automatically. 

BTW, they providing standalone cert. files for Linux (`.der file`), MacOS (`.mobileconfig file`).

Comment: perhaps just try using the Android oder iOS one, can't hurt to try..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment.

> @MarkusBlaurock
>   this is working only through MDM configuration at the moment. I passed
>   along the wish for a UI to configure it manually
>
> — Matthijs
>   Hoekstra (@mahoekst) [22. April 2014](https://twitter.com/mahoekst/status/458725795402240000)

According to a number of sources, like aboves tweet from Matthijs Hoekstra (working for Microsoft since 2002, member of the Windows Phone Team since 2013) and a news message on Windows Central (http://www.windowscentral.com/wi-fi-eap-tls-support-coming-windows-phone-some-point) this is only possible if you buy a MDM Solution like Microsoft Intune, since the UI does not offer any option to choose the second level handshake mechanism.

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not seem to see the need to make TTLS available soon. My employer thus recommends all employees to not buy Windows Phones, since they cannot login to our WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

TTLS is more commonly referred to as EAP-TTLS. From [Enterprise Wi-Fi authentication (EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn643706.aspx):

> EAP-TTLS is a standards-based EAP tunneling method that supports
>   mutual authentication and provides a secure tunnel for client
>   inclusion authentication by using EAP methods and other legacy
>   protocols.

---

> And there is no certificate for Windows Phone, only for Android, Windows, Mac OS and Linux

The certificate *should* be OK for Windows, too. Certificate are standardized in a couple of documents (like ITU's X.509 and IETF's RFC 5280), so they usually interoperate fairly well.

---

To manually configure EAP-TLS or EAP-TTLS authentication on a Windows Phone 8.1 device do the following:

1. When selecting an SSID for a connection that you do not currently have a profile for on the phone, you are presented with a sign in screen
2. The default setting for the “Connect using” box displays “user name+password”. For EAP-TLS and EAP-TTLS tap the “Connect using” box.
3. For EAP-TLS and EAP-TTLS tap “certificate” in the drop down menu. If you have more than one certificate installed on the phone then there will be a “choose a certificate” option box.
4. If you select that box you will get another screen with a list of the certificates that can be used for EAP-TLS or EAP-TTLS.
5. Once you select the certificate it will appear in the second box. Tapping the details button will show the detail information for the selected certificate.
6. Tap either the EAP method TLS or TTLS in the bottom “EAP Method” dropdown.
7. Once everything is configured, select done, and the phone will attempt to connect to the Wireless Access Point.